# Android app crashes when clicking on site icon in user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

When I go to my profile within the Android app, I can see the top X sites that I participate on. Clicking on the white space between the site title and right-side arrow brings up my user profile, along with my top-rated posts on that site. Lovely.

When I click on the site icon as the first thing to do upon loading the user page, I get an app crash.

---

- Stack Exchange: *1.0.8*
- Android: *4.3*

Comment: Reproduced in 1.0.9, Android: 4.4.2. Crash report sent, Log said it was a null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in the Stack Exchange 1.0.10 version released today. Sometimes, it may take a few additional seconds (while displaying no avatar, no top posts and no top tags), but it appears to no longer crash.

Thank you, Android development team!